# Assets 2.0 Install Error

Tags: assets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assets 2.0 update crashes CP & site](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4888/assets-2-0-update-crashes-cp-site)

Just went to install Assets 2.0 on a fresh install of EE 2.5.5 and got this PHP error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in
>   /var/sites/t/testdomainone.co.uk/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/helper.php
>   on line 205

Any idea what is causing the issue here?