# Assets 2.0 update crashes CP & site

Tags: assets

More specifically, when opening the modules>assets screen I get a whitescreen in both the site and the CP with the following:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in /home/ingedingen/domains/ingedingen.be/public_html/cmssystem/expressionengine/third_party/assets/helper.php on line 205
```

I've rolled back to assets1 in the mean time. This is on EE2.5.5.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please direct bug reports directly to developers - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open system/expressionengine/third_party/assets/helper.php and replace all occurrences of `static::` with `self::`, this error will go away.  We'll have an official release with the fix shortly.

Comment: Cheers Brad, I'll hold out for the release then, no rush.

Comment: 2.0.1 update went smoothly - all good now!